# Intercepting XHR Requests in webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, web-scraping

How we can intercept and see how many ajax or others content is being fired on page load while scraping ?

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://abc.om'
print('Starting URL','\n'*2 ,'-'*10 , url)
with sync_playwright() as p: 
    browser = p.chromium.launch() 
    page = browser.new_page() 
    
    page.on(
        "response", 
        lambda response: extract_response(response)
    ) 

    set_har = set()
    def extract_response(response):
        set_har.add((response.status,response.url))
        print(response.status, response.url)

    page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle", timeout=90000)
    page.goto(url, wait_until="load", timeout=90000) 

    # print(page.content()) 
    df = pd.DataFrame(set_har)
    df.to_csv(filename,index=False)

 
    page.context.close() 
    browser.close()
```